# how to remove vertical scroller

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to avoid the vertical scroll bar for my splitter.
I am using kendo UI splitter with two panes,
In the first pane I have grid.
depending upon the selected record in the grid my right side content height varying.
i am trying to set that varying height to the splitter.

I googled to get the right pane content height,but I am not able to get the exact height properly.

```
  var height = $('#splitter').prop('scrollHeight');
                    $('#splitter').height(height);
                    $("#splitter").css({ height: height })
```

I put this code in change event of grid,but it is not worked out for me.
I have defined splitter like

```
var splitter = $("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
                    panes: [
                                { collapsible: true, size: "48%" },
                                { collapsible: false, size: "52%" }],
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                            ]
});
```

can any one tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS (apply to the appropriate class):
**overflow-y:hidden;** - Use this for hiding the Vertical scroll

Another way (trigger this whenever you want)

```
 $("#splitter").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Comment: If I give overflow-y:hidden,If the content height is more then It will not display.

Comment: Then you have to calculate the height that after scrolling at some point it will disable the vertical scroll
\